# MKUserLocation — how to stop pulsating circles from blue point?

Tags: location, ios5

I use MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem to change tracking modes.
In MKUserTrackingModeNone mode I would like to see blue point without pulsating circle.

Is it possible?

P.S. As I see in standard Maps application pulsating circles used only for determining location, after that it is just a blue point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stop by itself on real device, showing the range of location,

but in iOS simulator it pulsating every time :)